# wp_get_nav_menu_items doesn't return custom post type item

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, routing

I try to achieve a menu like this (this is the actual menu).

[image]

There is a tree of projet coordinated by the wordpress menu that manage route and navigation.

Here is a scheme of the menu and the corresponding route.

```
PROJECT
 |
 |__ PAINT        (SITE_URL/paint)
 |    |__ post_1  (SITE_URL/paint/post_1)
 |
 |__ VIDEO        (SITE_URL/video)
      |__ post_2  (SITE_URL/video/post_2)
      |__ post_3  (SITE_URL/video/post_2)
```

First of all, know that post_1, post_2 and post_3 are custom post type generated here by [CPT UI](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/).

I need to get this menu in Js and in php, so I created a class in order to parse the menu returned by `wp_get_nav_menu_items`. You will find the class FP_Nav inside [`fp_nav.php`](https://gist.github.com/Liroo/972f5561eb75881f9706276c5a6c9fe4#file-fp_nav-php) this [git gist](https://gist.github.com/Liroo/972f5561eb75881f9706276c5a6c9fe4#file-fp_nav-php).

As the route doesn't really exist while it's set in the wordpress menu as `Custom link` (ie. /paint, /video in the below scheme). I use an action `do_parse_request` in order to prevent the native `parse_request` if the url match some of mine in my menu and let the `parse_request` execute if not. (find my custom *"router"* in [`fp_router.php`](https://gist.github.com/Liroo/972f5561eb75881f9706276c5a6c9fe4#file-fp_router-php) also in the previous [git gist](https://gist.github.com/Liroo/972f5561eb75881f9706276c5a6c9fe4#file-fp_router-php)

Here is my [`functions.php`](https://gist.github.com/Liroo/972f5561eb75881f9706276c5a6c9fe4#file-functions-php) (in the same git gist) in order to know the order of how it's executed.

The problem is:

When I load my class FP_Nav that is supposed to get all the item in the menu using `wp_get_nav_menu_items` and that should be run before the headers are sent (because I need to parse the request using the menu items), this function `wp_get_nav_menu_items` does not return any of my custom post that is set in the menu.

I declare my CPT in the action `init` but I suspect that my class FP_Nav is loaded before the CPT is loaded because in the `index.php` (template file), the menu got every fields and if I declare the CPT outside the `init` action as well.

Also I have to load this class BEFORE the headers are sent so I can move out the CPT declaration outstide the `init` action but I'm not sure it's a good idea and somehow I would like to produce good code so if there is another solution, I'm on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by putting classes init in a wordpress hook `wp_loaded` as:

```
function instantiate_class() {
  FP_Nav();
  FP_Router();
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'instantiate_class', 100 );
```

which is before the `do_parse_request` action and after my CPT init in the hook `init`.

I don't know if it is the best way to handle this but it works well for now.